# Update data using sweetalert ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, sweetalert

How can I update content using *sweet alert ajax request* with user provided input?

The data is not updating after the ajax request.

**Code**

```
<script>
    function change_stock(item_id) {
        swal({
            title: "Edit Stock!!",
            text: "Enter the stock No: you wanded to change",
            type: "input",
            showCancelButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
        }, function (inputValue) {
            if (inputValue === false)
                return false;
            if (inputValue === "") {
                swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
                return false
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "edit_stock.php",
                    data: {stock_no: inputValue, itemid: item_id},
                    success: function () {
                        swal({title: "Updated!", text: "Stock No: has Changed", type: "success", },
                                function () {
                                    location.reload(true);
                                });
                    }
                });

            }, 2000);
        });
    }

</script>
```

**edit_stock.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['stock_no']) && isset($_POST['itemid'])) {
    include("connection.php");
    $item_id = $_POST['itemid'];
    $stock = $_POST['stock_no'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `item` SET `item_stock`= " . $stock . " WHERE `item_id` =" . $item_id;
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo 'updated';
    } else {
        header('location: ./');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you narrowed down to where exactly the problem lies?

Comment: the error is on ajax request

Comment: @Aadarsh   have u get  $stock , $item_id in edit_stock.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "edit_stock.php",
                data: {stock_no: inputValue, itemid: item_id},
                success: function () {
                    swal({title: "Updated!", text: "Stock No: has Changed", type: "success" }).then(function() {

                                location.reload(true);

                });
            });
});
```